A cart plows into a Monster. What damage was done to the Monster?
I know the DMG has stats for Airborne and Waterborne Vehicles (largely thanks to this question), and I'm comfortable adapting that and the ships from Ghosts of Saltmarsh.
While there's rules for HP and AC for objects, and I'm sure I could figure out the damage done to an object from a monster, I can't find rules for the damage done to a monster from an object like a cart, wagon, ship, city bus, starship, etc.
Are there existing rules to determine what happens when a vehicle which is traveling with enough force to do damage to something hits something else, especially if that something else is a monster?

Misread "cart" as "cat"; disappointed by question body. Voting to close /s

Dammit, now I want to read rules about cats hitting monsters at high speeds. Where is my gnomish cheeta cavalry trample rules?

Wasn't that in 2nd ed? The Glory of Rome Campaign Sourcebook. <- I am joking.

Some vehicles have this information
Spelljamming Vessels (from S:AiS:AAG 25)

When a spelljamming ship crashes into something that could reasonably damage it, both the ship and the creature or object it struck take bludgeoning damage based on the size of the struck object, as shown in the Crash Damage table...




Size of Creature or Object Struck
Bludgeoning Damage




Large
4d10


Huge
8d10


Gargantuan
16d10



Seagoing Vessels (from Ghosts of Saltmarsh 199)

If a ship moves into the space occupied by a creature or object, the ship might crash...A creature struck by a ship must make a Dexterity saving throw with a DC equal to 10 + the ship's Strength modifier, taking damage based on the ship's size (as shown by the Crash Damage table) on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.




Size
Bludgeoning Damage




Small
1d6


Medium
1d10


Large
4d10


Huge
8d10


Gargantuan
16d10



Infernal War Machines (from BG: DiA 218-219)
Tormentor (Huge Vehicle, 3000lb):

Crushing Wheels. The Tormentor can move through the space of any Medium or smaller creature. When it does, the creature must succeed on a DC 13 Dexterity saving throw or take 11 (2d10) bludgeoning damage and be knocked prone. If the creature was already prone, it takes an extra 11 (2d10) bludgeoning damage. This trait can't be used against a particular creature more than once each turn.

Scavenger (Huge Vehicle, 9000lb):

Crushing Wheels. The Scavenger can move through the space of any Large or smaller creature. When it does, the creature must succeed on a DC 12 Dexterity saving throw or take 16 (3d10) bludgeoning damage and be knocked prone. If the creature was already prone, it takes an extra 16 (3d10) bludgeoning damage. This trait can't be used against a particular creature more than once each turn.

Demon Grinder (Gargantuan Vehicle, 12000lb):

Crushing Wheels. The Demon Grinder can move through the space of any Large or smaller creature. When it does, the creature must succeed on a DC 11 Dexterity saving throw or take 22 (4d10) bludgeoning damage and be knocked prone. If the creature was already prone, it takes an extra 22 (4d10) bludgeoning damage. This trait can't be used against a particular creature more than once each turn.

More mundane vehicles
As far as I know, there aren't rules for more mundane vehicles like carts and wagons - although it wouldn't surprise me to find 'runaway cart' as an encounter in some adventure or another.  Based on the above examples, the pattern is clearly that a creature in harm's way is permitted a Dex save to avoid damage, with easier saves for larger and more ponderous vehicles.  Failed Dex saves result in damage proportional to the size and mass of the vehicle, to which a mundane vehicle would add the size and mass of the beasts drawing it.  Something resembling 4d6 for a wagon drawn by a pair of large draft horses down to d4 for a cart pulled by a single medium donkey seems appropriate.
